# Insert result of userform into heading

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, userform

I need to insert the result of my userform into a header but i don't know how to combine my codes into a final project : ***Photos and code below***

i need the header OK Button to 
**1**: Format the header according to my header code depending on what sheet i want, in this case the sheet called metals

**2**. After it says "Summary of Metals in "_____" <-(Soil/Sediment...etc depending on which box is checked)

**3**. Insert what ever text is entered into the userform text box. (no code written yet).

**The final result.** = For this particular sheet would be the header saying "Summary of Metals in Soil, 100 Main Street, USA"

**All help is appreciated!**

The code below inserts the result into A1 just temporary
    Private Sub Cancel_Click()
    Me.Hide
    End Sub

```
Private Sub OK_Click()

'--- Insert the correct matrix Wording ---
    If Check_Soil.Value = -1 Then
    Range("A1").Value = "Soil"

ElseIf Check_Sediment.Value = -1 Then
    Range("A1").Value = "Sediment"

ElseIf Check_Ground_Water.Value = -1 Then
    Range("A1").Value = "Ground Water"

ElseIf Check_Surface_Water.Value = -1 Then
    Range("A1").Value = "Surface Water"
End If
Me.Hide

MsgBox "Completed", vbOKOnly
End Sub

Private Sub Check_Soil_Click()

'--- Checks if the Soil Button is Clicked ---
If Check_Soil.Value = True Then
    Check_Surface_Water.Value = False
    Check_Ground_Water.Value = False
    Check_Sediment.Value = False
Else
    Check_Soil.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Check_Surface_Water_Click()

'--- Checks if the Surface Water Button is Clicked ---
If Check_Surface_Water.Value = True Then
    Check_Soil.Value = False
    Check_Ground_Water.Value = False
    Check_Sediment.Value = False
Else
    Check_Surface_Water.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Check_Ground_Water_Click()

'--- Checks if the Ground Water Button is Clicked ---
If Check_Ground_Water.Value = True Then
    Check_Surface_Water.Value = False
    Check_Soil.Value = False
    Check_Sediment.Value = False
Else
    Check_Ground_Water.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Check_Sediment_Click()

'--- Checks if the Sediment Button is Clicked ---
If Check_Sediment.Value = True Then
    Check_Surface_Water.Value = False
    Check_Soil.Value = False
    Check_Ground_Water.Value = False
Else
    Check_Sediment.Enabled = True
End If
End Sub
```

**My OTHER CODE:**

```
SubSelect_Correct_Sheet()
' Select_Correct_Sheet Macro
Sheets("Metals").Select
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
    .PrintTitleColumns = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = ""
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = "&""Arial,Bold""Summary of Metals in "
    .CenterHeader = ""
    .RightHeader = ""
    .LeftFooter = ""
    .CenterFooter = ""
    .RightFooter = ""
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
    .PrintHeadings = False
    .PrintGridlines = False
    .PrintComments = xlPrintNoComments
    .PrintQuality = 600
    .CenterHorizontally = False
    .CenterVertically = False
    .Orientation = xlPortrait
    .Draft = False
    .FirstPageNumber = xlAutomatic
    .Order = xlDownThenOver
    .BlackAndWhite = False
    .Zoom = 100
    .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
    .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
    .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
    .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two changes

1- change your OK_Click into this:

```
Private Sub OK_Click()
    Dim headerText As String
    Select Case True
        Case Check_Soil.value: headerText = "Soil"
        Case Check_Sediment.value: headerText = "Sediment"
        Case Check_Ground_Water.value: headerText = "Ground Water"
        Case Check_Surface_Water.value: headerText = "Surface Water"
    End Select

    headerText = headerText & ", " & TextBox1.value ' <-- assuming this is the name of your textbox
    FormatHeader headerText ' <-- now invoke the header formatting sub with parameter
    MsgBox "Completed"
End Sub
```

2- Change your routine of formatting the header (old name was `Select_Correct_Sheet` I gave it a new name, `FormatHeader`). I should have a parameter `text` in its declaration and only one line will change, the one where the text is assigned in order to add the provided parameter.

```
Sub FormatHeader(text As String)
    ' ....
    .LeftHeader = "&""Arial,Bold""Summary of Metals in " & text '<-- add the text parameter into header here
    ' ....
End Sub
```

Comment: ....Thank you! Your solution was perfect and much more eloquent than what i had written. I'm going to throw a curveball at you.....If i have multiple sheets with different names, lets say sheet1, sheet2, sheet 3. Is there a way to add in a code to say. Summary of Sheet1 in soil" then next sheet is "Summary of Sheet2 in Soil"...etc?...I can't stress enough how much i appreciate your help!

Comment: It would be to generate all the header's text inside `OK_Click`: `headerText = "Summary of & ActiveSheet.name & " in " & headerText & ", " & TextBox1.value '`. Then in the `Sub FormatHeader` : `.LeftHeader = "&""Arial,Bold""" & text`.

Comment: You're answers are marvelous

Comment: ....my good friend ash, what if my sheet name was "LOL" but i wanted the header part to say "Laugh out Loud"?